# How to match SQL server functions in Hive

Tags: python-3.x, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I am trying to write the Stored Procedure for SQL equivalent in Hive. I managed to translate the first two:

```
DECLARE @ReloadMonths as INT=15

set reloadMonths=15


DECLARE @Anchor_DT as DATE =EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1);

set anchor_dt=select last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')`)
```

But I am having troubles translating the following two:

```
DECLARE @YearMonth as INT=C_II.Common.FN_COM_DATEToYearMonth(@Anchor_DT);

set yearMonth=(anchor_dt,'yyyy-MM')

DECLARE @StartYearMonth as INT =ISNULL(@StartYearMonth_Inp,C_II.Common.FN_COM_DATEToYearMonth(DATEADD(MM,-@ReloadMonths+1,@Anchor_DT)));

set startYearMonth=${hiveconf:${hiveconf:startYearMonth}};
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: could you please describe in more details about your requirements and add some more details regarding expectation to the question. Thanks

Comment: C_II.Common.FN_COM_DATEToYearMonth this lookslike some user function specific to your project. can you explain what it does?

Comment: also you have calculated yearMonth and not using it on later statements. which date or value your are expecting in final variable startYearMonth ? is it 2018-04-30?? please confirm.

Comment: I hope I was able to match the requirements. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your requirements was not much clear in the question. Also it seems that this function 'C_II.Common.FN_COM_DATEToYearMonth' is specific to your project and it's not a standard sql server function.

Lets breakdown it in step by steps:

If we run below statements in sql server:

```
DECLARE @Anchor_DT as DATE =EOMONTH(Getdate(),-1);
select @Anchor_DT;
```

It will give you date as: 2019-06-30
whereas the hive conversion you made for this is incorrect.

```
select last_day(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

It will give you last day of current month as '2019-07-31' so the right and equivalent coversion to sql server would be as:

```
select DATE_SUB(current_date(),DAY(current_date()));
```

This will return you date as :'2019-06-30'

The last two statements in your question was not very clear but looks like you are expecting below conversion.

```
select date_format('${hiveconf:anchor_dt}','yyyy-MM');
```

It will return as : 2019-06

```
"DECLARE @StartYearMonth as INT =ISNULL(@StartYearMonth_Inp,C_II.Common.FN_COM_DATEToYearMonth(DATEADD(MM,-@ReloadMonths+1,@Anchor_DT)));"
```

I have converted above statement in sql server as shown below:

```
select format((DATEADD(MM,-@ReloadMonths+1,@Anchor_DT)),'yyyy-MM');
```

This will return date in sql server as : 2018-04

Answer to your question:
create a hive script and save it on your hdfs location.(testdatehive.hql)

```
select date_format('${hiveconf:anchor_dt}','yyyy-MM');
select date_format(add_months('${hiveconf:anchor_dt}',-${hiveconf:reloadMonths}+1),'yyyy-MM');
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declare integer variable
declare -i reloadMonths=15
echo $reloadMonths

echo "Executing the hive query - get anchor date and store it in shell variable"

anchor_dt=$(hive -e "select DATE_SUB(current_date(),DAY(current_date()));")
echo $anchor_dt

echo "Pass anchor_date & reloadMonths to hive script"

hive --hiveconf anchor_dt=$anchor_dt --hiveconf reloadMonths=$reloadMonths -f hdfs://hostname/user/vikct001/dev/hadoop/hivescripts/testdatehive.hql

echo "Executing the hive query - ends"
```

Here is your shell output:

```
15
Executing the hive query - get anchor date and store it in shell variable
2019-06-30
Pass anchor_date & reloadMonths to hive script
2019-06
2018-04
```

Let me know if this works.